# Sending email using cake PHP in a table format

Tags: cakephp

I need to send an email, consisting of the details of products purchased by a person in a shopping cart. I need to send it in a table format. Please help me. How can I do it??

Comment: actually the body of the email should contain details of the products purchased by a single person.can you explain how to set up html views. I am new to cake php

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up the HTML views and then use that view instead of palin/text email
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html

You can also refer this links also 
http://chetan4cake.blogspot.in/2012/07/email-in-cakephp-20.html